# Bubble Sort with for loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, sorting, bubble-sort

I just got started with writing sorting algorithms. 
Currently I am learning the Bubble Sort algorithm, I found the following online and it's working fine:

```
const arr = [3, 2, 6, 9, 3, 5];

const bubbleSort = array => {
  do {
    var isSorted = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;
        isSorted = false;
      }
    }
  } while(!isSorted)
  return array
};
```

Output:

```
[ 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9 ]
```

However, when I try to write it using an if statement instead of a while loop like the following, it doesn't work as expected:

```
const arr = [3, 2, 6, 9, 3, 5];

const bubbleSort = (array) => {
  let isSorted = false;
  if(!isSorted) {
    isSorted = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
        var temp = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
        isSorted = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

Output:

```
[ 2, 3, 6, 3, 5, 9 ]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The if statement is a one-off whereas the while loop keeps doing it while it isn't sorted.

Comment: The `if` statement is not equivalent of `while`...

Comment: If statement is just a conditional statement, but while statement is the loop statement. Here you need to use a loop.

Comment: Why did you replace the `do { } while()` with an `if() { }` ? What was your thought behind that change?

Comment: Also note that you're running out of array bounds in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

We need the while loop for bubble sort.

If we remove `while` then we will 'bubble' only once through the whole array. For example if the

```
[3, 2, 6, 9, 3, 5];
```

here 3 (first element) is larger than 2 (second element) so we swap them and now we have

```
[2, 3, 6, 9, 3, 5]
```

When we continue with the for loop we approach 3 (6th element) that is smaller so we swap it with 9 (5th element). AND continue forward.

```
[2, 3, 6, 3, 9, 5]
```

from here we will only go up but we can analyse the situation. We can see that 3 (4th element) is smaller than 6(third element) but the for loop is way ahead so we will not be in a situation where we swap it with a larger element.
So we have to start "bubbling" again from the beginning and we need to do it until everything is sorted. This will happen when there are nothing to swap, because we set `isSorted=false` when ever we swap. After array is sorted we will do a last pass where we will check every adjacent pair and if they are all sorted the swap will not occur and `isSorted` will be `true`

TLDR; we need `while` because 'bubbling' might need several passes through the array.

Answer (score 0):

while loop is an easy way to implement Bubble Sort, otherwise you will need O(n²) algorithm with nested for loops instead, `if else` statements will not work:

```
const arr = [3, 2, 6, 9, 3, 5];
const bubbleSort = array => {
    var length = array.length;
    //Number of passes
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        //Notice that j < (length - i)
        for (var j = 0; j < (length - i - 1); j++) { 
            //Compare the adjacent positions
            if(array[j] > array[j+1]) {
                //Swap the numbers
                var tmp = array[j];  //Temporary variable to hold the current number
                array[j] = array[j+1]; //Replace current number with adjacent number
                array[j+1] = tmp; //Replace adjacent number with current number
            }
        }        
    }
    return array
}
bubbleSort(arr)
// expected output: [2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```

You can also see Bubble Sort pseudocode here: [Bubble Sort Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)